# D-orbitals of point group C2v

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, symmetry

I'm trying to construct an MO diagram for cisplatin, which has C2v symmetry. However, there is no Mulliken label for the d(x^2-y^2) orbital in the character table. Does this orbital not form molecular orbitals in C2v symmetry?

Comment: X^2 and Y^2 lie in A1, so linear combinations of those do, too.